# CSS how to avoid line break between elements with css?

Tags: css, html

```css
div#banner>img {
  float: left;
  background-color: #4b634b;
  height: 265px;
  width: 80%;
}

ul {
  float: left;
  background-color: #769976;
  width: 162px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <header>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="1.html" class="active">one</a></li>
          <li><a href="2.html">two</a></li>
          <li><a href="3.html">three</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div id="banner">
        <img src="pic.jpg">
      </div>
    </header>
    <!--...rest of body and wrapper...-->
  </div>
</body>
```

hello, i googled a lot but got no good answer yet, the problem is that i want to have the nav on the top left, and the banner attached to it towards the right border of the wrapper, now with the css it works but only in fullscreen, at a certain point it inserts a linebreak between thoes two,
how can i prevent this?
thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change both `width` values to percentage values that sum up to less than 100%.

ADDITION AFTER COMMENT:

You can set the image element to `width: calc(100% - 162px);` This will make it the full width minus the 162px needed for the other element

Comment: thanks for the answer, i am ok with the picture changing size but the wrapper must be the size of 162px, how can i fix this then?

Answer (score 0):

Your question wasn't that clear but I think the problem is that your elements are over the viewport width. 
Try setting the width using a percent or dynamically

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="wrapper">
  <header>
   <nav>
    <ul>
     <li>
      <a class="active" href="1.html">one</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="2.html">two</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="3.html">three</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
   <div id="banner"><img src="pic.jpg"></div>
   <p>Content here</p>
   <p></p>
  </header>
 </div>
 <style>
 div#banner>img {
    background-color:#4b634b;
    height:265px;
    width: 80%;
 }

 ul {
    float:left;
    background-color: #769976;
    width:20%x;
 }
 #wrapper{
    width:100%;
   }


 </style>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the great help guys, i tried several stuff because there were some other things which made it a bit more difficult

like the wrapper has a format too so absolute was not working out

probably my fault cause i didnt asked precise enough, thanks tho for the great and fast help

"You can set the image element to width: calc(100% - 162px); This will make it the full width minus the 162px needed for the other element"

was the way to go, thanks to johannes and everybody else!